# SVN -- Unable to commit newly added files

Tags: xcode, svn

I have deleted few files from my project. After deletion i have added few new viewcontrollers. After this when i tried to commit my project in SVN, i facing an issue saying **"The working copy < Project Name > failed to add files"**.

Below image shows the issue information.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to commit all files the together?

Comment: yes, i am trying to commit all files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed these steps to resolve my issue

[image]

In the above image, you can observe selected files having **!** mark. The problem is with these files. So we need to remove these files to fix the issue.

For removing these files follow below steps.

1. Select all the files having **!** mark.
2. After selection, Right click on the files.
3. Select **Discard Changes**
4. Click **Discard Changes** in confirmation dialogue.

Below images may help you to get clarification on this process.

[image]

[image]

After this you can commit all the files at a time.

I followed these steps to fix the issue and to commit all my code files into SVN successfully.